# Force VS to update initialization code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, initialization

VS2008, VB.NET, Windows 7 Pro

I am creating a component to be dragged-and-dropped from the VS Toolbox onto
a developer's Form.

The component can display a UI at any time after it's Sited through which the developer can enter a value.

I would like to embed that value in an executable subsequently compiled by VS, so that the executable later "knows" that value.

If I put that value into a component Property, VS writes the value into the auto-generated Initialization code for the Form, which determines what gets embedded.  VS does this reliably when it Sites the component.

It also does it when the developer adds a new Component to the Form, Deletes one, or changes a Property value with the VS PropertyBrowser.

But the value is not available until after Site, when VS has already completed its update, and I can't rely on Developers to do the VS UI work required to get VS to do it again. Does anyone know how to *programmatically* force VS to update the auto-generated Initialization code at a moment of my choosing in Designtime? (I.e. just after the developer uses my UI to set a value?)

Many thanks for your wisdom.

Comment: I dont know that all your suppositions are true. The designer code will be updated simply as a result of adding the Component to the form or any property changing - what else is needed. You should expand on `after the developer uses my UI to set a value` because if they make changes, those are instantly added to the designer code.  If there is something getting missed, it might be a serializiation problem.  If "the value" you mention defaults to an illegal value, you could throw an exception to force them to do their job.  Hard to tell what exactly you are after.

Comment: @Plutonix:  Thanks.  I don't rule out that my installation of VS is wonky, but a change in a Property is NOT instantly added to the designer code if that change is made in code.  If the change is made via the VS Property Browser, it works fine.  This suggests that the update mechanism is driven by events fired by the VS Property Browser, which does me no good at all.  I DID find a solution, adding a dummy component to the component's owner form (and then removing it) by using .CreateComponent and .DeleteComponent through the owner form's IDesignerHost.  Not ideal, but I'll take what I can get.

Comment: @Plutonix:  I am suitably embarrassed to say that I ran into this issue a year ago and asked about it on SO then, which I don't remember at all.  I solved the problem then in much the same way I did this time:  by removing the component and re-siting it, which provoked the VS serialization I was after.

Comment: I am lost.  The OP asks about `developer uses my UI to set a value` which I infer to be a Property.  Now you are talking about a `change made in code` - I have no idea *what* code?  The component? The UIDesigner? The code using the component?  You can have design properties which are not visible to the user. If you designate an illegal default value for it, the property will always look changed and be saved/updated.  Hard to be specific without a more concrete idea of what you are up to.